# window.requestFileSystem not working in android 7.0 and 7.1.1

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

[image]I am using cordova widow.requestFileSystem in my mobilefirst hybrid application to save file in mobile,It is working fine in android versions less than 7.0 and 7.1.1 but in android 7.0 and 7.1.1 it is throwing error code 9.Attached logcat logs for android 7.0

```
 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,function(success){alert(success);}, function(error){alert("error occuered--"+JSON.stringify(error));});
```

Comment: What version of MobileFirst are you using ?

Comment: IBM MobileFirst Platform Studiov7.1.0.00

Comment: Are permissions enabled? Also, is it working on Android 6.0/

Comment: @VivinK-yes enabled and it is working on android 6.0

Comment: Can you provide the logcat output you see ?

Comment: @Srik- attached to this question, please have a look